# Custom sign in page not redirecting correctly in next auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

**api/[...nextauth].js**

```
export default NextAuth({
providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
    name: 'Credentials',
    credentials: {
        email: { label: 'E-mail', type: 'text', placeholder: 'me@gmail.com' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password', placeholder: 'my password' },
    },
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
        return { email: 'x', password: 'y'}
    },
    }),
]
});
```

**pages/auth/signin.tsx**

```
export default function SignIn() {
const [password, setPassword] = useState(null)
const [email, setEmail] = useState(null)

const onSubmit = () => {
    signIn("Credentials", { email, password })
}

return (
    <div>
    <label>
        Email
        <input name="email" type="text" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
    </label>
    <label>
        Password
        <input name="password" type="password"  onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
    </label>
    <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Sign in!</button>
    </div>
)
}
```

onSubmit redirects to the default sign in page `/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fsignin`, **instead of correctly signin in and redirecting to `/`. How to fix this?**

I am experiencing the same issue also with the custom sign form using `form` tag (https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages#credentials-sign-in)

Comment: can you please provide simple example code for login using NextAuth in Next JS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution, but I think the documentation is misleading.

What I did is add an id property to my [...nextauth].js provider :

```js
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Adresse email', type: 'email' },
        password: { label: 'Mot de passe', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        console.log(credentials);
        const user = { id: 1, name: 'Jean Dupont', email: 'jean.dupont@yopmail.com' };

        if (user.id === 1) {
        // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
          return user;
        }
        // If you return null or false then the credentials will be rejected
        return null;
        // You can also Reject this callback with an Error or with a URL:
        // throw new Error('error message') // Redirect to error page
        // throw '/path/to/redirect'        // Redirect to a URL
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/login',
  },
});
```

I then called the signIn function as before, replacing the name argument with the id and route to '/' as initially desired

```js
// ...
await signIn('credentials', { email, password, callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/` });
// ...
```

The problem is that the documentation does not mention the use of the id attribute in the provider. It is only mentioned in the multiple providers example code : https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials#multiple-providers and there is also nothing in the credentials provider configuration page : https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials-provider.

Comment: adding the id helped. thank you!

Comment: Incredible, the matching ID worked!

Comment: This relly helped! Was stuck with this in NextJS 13 and adding `id` with the same as name helped fix redirection problem.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are really customizing the whole thing, you can add a hidden input.

```
<form method="post" action="/api/auth/signin/email">
    <input type="hidden" name="callbackUrl" value="/dashboard" />
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: wow, didn't know about this, not sure why it is not mentioned in the doc anywhere (or at least make it easier to find)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, try changing the signIn call to:

signIn("Credentials", {redirect: false, email, password})

Comment: didn't change anything. still sending me to the standard sign in page, and when I try to sign in there it redirects me to `about:blank#blocked` with this error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL`

Comment: disregard the about:black/error part of the comment, it was another issue

Comment: Great solution! No reddirect no matter how the form is validated!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing middleware.js or middleware.ts to below:

```
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export default withAuth({
    pages: {
        signIn: '/auth/signIn',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

```
    {providers &&
      Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <button
          className="p-3 rounded bg-white w-full text-sm mb-2"
          key={provider.id}
          onClick={() =>
            signIn(provider.id, {
              redirect: true,
              callbackUrl: "/dashboard",
            })
          }
        >
          Continue with {provider.name}
        </button>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a callback function in the next-auth configuration options that returns the baseUrl as mentioned in the official documentation [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#redirect-callback).

```
export const options = {
    providers: [...],
    callbacks: [
       async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
           return baseUrl;
       }
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Guys if you are using app folder structure in next 14 your api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts folder must be at same folder auth/signin page. and if you are using next 14 route grouping like (auth) carefull this folder leveling